# TestLink 1.9.20 installation problem with $tlCfg->testcase_cfg->glue_character = '-';

Tags: installation, xampp, testlink

all,

I am having a problem when trying to install TestLink on Windows using the [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testlink/testlink_installation.htm)

These are the steps I am following:

1. Download and install Bitnamin v5.6.40-1 (XAMPP) on c drive – **OK**,
2. Open XAMPP control panel, start Apache and MySQL - **OK**
3. Download TestLink 1.9.20, unzip it and copy to ‘C:\xampp\htdocs‘ - **OK**
4. Modify file ‘config.inc.php’ in the ‘C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink’ - **OK**

$tlCfg->log_path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\logs';

$g_repositoryPath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\upload_area';

5. Open http://localhost/Testlink - **FAILS** with the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "results" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\cfg\const.inc.php:410 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\install\index.php(20): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\cfg\const.inc.php on line 410

I’ve added the following line in const.inc.php to initialize the object:

$tlCfg = new stdClass();

It seems to fix the problem. http://localhost/Testlink opens fine now.

6. Proceed with the TestLink installation (http://localhost/Testlink).

The pre-requisites check is **OK**.
The installation **FAILS** at Process TestLink Setup (after I enter Database Admin login/password to define MySQL access and TestLink admin login/password):

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "glue_character" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\config.inc.php:192 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\install\installNewDB.php(37): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\config.inc.php on line 192

The problem is with this line of the code:

$tlCfg->testcase_cfg->glue_character = '-';

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your config.ini.php and add this line:
`$tlCfg->testcase_cfg = new stdClass();`
`$tlCfg->testcase_cfg->glue_character = '-';`

If you face the same error with other variable just try to do the same thing.